# Django file browser doesn't work

Tags: python, django, django-grappelli, django-filebrowser, django-media

I have installed Django file browser and added `grappelli` and `filebrowser` to my installed apps. And did every thing said in documention but when I browse `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/filebrowser/` I got 404 page not found error. What's the problem? I configured my media settings like this:

```
# Media files
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/media/admin/'
FILEBROWSER_DIRECTORY = '/media/'
```

Comment: What versions did you install?

Comment: @SimeonVisser FileBrowser 3.5 and Grappelli 2.5.1 from GitHub. Actually I cloned them and use their source folders.

Comment: Do you see anything at `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/filebrowser/browse/`? According to the source code there's no base URL for filebrowser, only specific URLs.

Comment: @SimeonVisser I see `Bad Request (400)` page at `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/filebrowser/browse/`

Comment: Could you try `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/filebrowser/upload/`? Perhaps you need some additional parameters for `/browse/`.

Comment: @SimeonVisser No, Again I see same error page but it's not django error page and I think it's for file browser. And what do you mean by additional parameters for `/browse/` ?

Comment: Parameters in the URL. But this shows that filebrowser works, it's just that something isn't configured properly yet. Does `DEBUG = True` tell you anything?

Comment: @SimeonVisser In my uls.py I've added these two lines: `(r'^grappelli/', include('grappelli.urls')),(r'^admin/filebrowser/', include(site.urls)),`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your FILEBROWSER_DIRECTORY setting. It should have absolute path.

Unfortunately, the error is hidden by the nasty 400 Bad Request, as explained [in this ticket](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-updates/f_ZqFRWkJik).

Answer (score 0):

Just solved the exact same problem, and it's the oldest one in the book: **permissions**
(facepalm)

- make sure your `media` dir is chmod-ed to `755`
- create `media/uploads` dir and also chmod it to `755`

In settings.py, I don't use the `FILEBROWSER_DIRECTORY` (I guess that `uploads` is the default)

I really think that throwing **`400 Bad Request`** is utterly useless and anoying, but oh well...

---

Just a related note: I don't think there is anything at `/admin/filebrowser/`, it just gives me a 404. Please correct me it I'm missing something here :)